# python: what is go keyword in generator expression while operating dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

This is a fairly simple query while I was checking out various discussions on Dictionary comprehension over here.
SO I did something like this:

```
newlist=[{v:k} for k,v in dicnew.items() if v==value]
>>> newlist
[{2: 'a'}, {2: 'ac'}, {2: 'b'}, {2: 'love'}]
```

What i did next is something like this:

```
newlist.setdefault(v,[]).append((v,k) for k,v in dicnew.items() if v==value)
>>> newlist
{'go': [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x01E98D50>]}
```

What just happened? What is this 'go'?

Comment: `go` is the last value of `v` in your interpreter.

Comment: what makes this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You called `.setdefault()` with *a* value of `v`:

```
newlist.setdefault(v,[])
```

and `v` must have been defined already and set to `'go'`. Had you run this code in a new interpreter, or executed `del v` first, Python would have raised a `NameError` exception instead:

```
>>> newlist = {}
>>> newlist.setdefault(v,[]).append((v,k) for k,v in dicnew.items() if v==value)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'v' is not defined
>>> v = 'go'
>>> newlist.setdefault(v, [])
[]
>>> newlist
{'go': []}
```

The `setdefault()` part is executed before the `.append()` method is executed. The `v` name used in the generator expression inside the `.append()` method has *nothing* to do with the `v` name used in the `.setdefault()` call.

In Python 2.7 and earlier, list comprehension variables 'leak' to the parent scope:

```
>>> [foo for foo in range(3)]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> foo
2
```

As such, `v` was set in your previous loop, and the last value assigned to it is `'go'`.

If you wanted to 'invert' a dictionary by collecting a list of keys for each value, use:

```
from collections import defaultdict

keys_for_value = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in original_dict.iteritems():
    keys_for_value[value].append(key)
```

If you must *insist* on a one-liner, use `itertools.groupby` and sorting:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

v = itemgetter(1)
keys_for_value = {value: [k for k, v in items] for value, items in groupby(sorted(original_dict.iteritems(), key=v, key=v)}
```

This is going to be slower, as you need to sort the dictionary items first (cost O(n log n)) before looping over the sorted results (itself O(n), so a total of O(n) + O(n log n)), as opposed to a simple O(n) complexity of using `defaultdict` and a `for` loop.

Comment: {'a': 2, 'ac': 2, 'b': 2, 'love': 2, 'yo': 'show', 'no': 'go'}=dicnew

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with `dictnew`. You have a name `v` defined in your local interpreter session. It was probably the last value assigned to `v` in the previous loop.

Comment: em, well v here is not defined, its part of the comprehension.nope didnt set v to anything

Comment: @user2290820: Try it: `print v`.

Comment: ok i got it.but why does that generator expression happen>i thought that shouldnt happen, iteration with dict() and there's no next() function going on

Comment: @user2290820: You pass a generator expression to `.append()`. `.append()` only adds *one* value to a list. It does *not* expect a sequence. Use `.extend()` if you expect the generator expression to be iterated over.

Comment: ok got it.it gives error just like mentioned above, NameError. So this kind of dictionary comprehension is not possible.

Comment: @user2290820: I suspect what you are looking for is normally done with a `defaultdict(list)` object then a loop: `from collections import defaultdict`, `result = defaultdict(list)`, `for k, v in somedict.iteritems(): result[v].append(k)`.

Comment: @user2290820: That builds a dictionary mapping values to lists of keys. That sort of structure cannot be built with a dict comprehension, no.

Comment: funny. v is getting assigned to 'no' key which has 'go' value while using setdefault. also v is being assigned without even defining v before! extend does work but gives this: {'go': [(2, 'a'), (2, 'ac'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'love')]}

Comment: defaultdict(list) but loop is still there for k, v in somedict.iteritems(). anyway newlist.setdefault(value,[]).extend(whatever) worked : value=2. Thanks